# django serializer data extract nouns

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nltk

I am trying to use nltk in my django rest app to extract nouns bad verbs:

My WIP function looks like following:

```
@api_view(['GET'])        
def test(request):
    verbs=[]
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
    print(serializer.data)
    text = nltk.word_tokenize(str(serializer.data))
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(text)
    #print(tags)

    for tag in tags:
        if tag[1][0] == 'V':
            verbs.extend(tag)
    return Response(verbs)
```

Line `print(serializer.data)` prints following:

```
[OrderedDict([(u'id', 17), ('title', u'Browse through the list of books'), ('how_often', u'DO'), ('how_important_task', u'EI'), ('role', u'reader'), ('why_perform_task', u''), ('why_important_task', None), ('sequence_of_actions', u''), ('tools_used', u''), ('special_training_required', False), ('what_training_required', u''), ('what_can_go_wrong', u''), ('effects_of_task', u''), ('special_vocabulary_used', u''), ('people_involved', u''), ('any_improvements', u''), ('how_important_improvement', u''), ('benefits_of_improvement', u''), ('stakeholder', 2L), ('project', 1L)]),

OrderedDict([(u'id', 18), ('title', u'Search for a book'), ('how_often', u'DS'), ('how_important_task', u'EI'), ('role', u'reader'), ('why_perform_task', u''), ('why_important_task', None), ('sequence_of_actions', u''), ('tools_used', u''), ('special_training_required', False), ('what_training_required', u''), ('what_can_go_wrong', u''), ('effects_of_task', u''), ('special_vocabulary_used', u''), ('people_involved', u''), ('any_improvements', u''), ('how_important_improvement', u'RI'), ('benefits_of_improvement', u''), ('stakeholder', 2L), ('project', 1L)]),

OrderedDict([(u'id', 19), ('title', u'Request a book'), ('how_often', u'WO'), ('how_important_task', u'RI'), ('role', u'reader'), ('why_perform_task', u''), ('why_important_task', None), ('sequence_of_actions', u''), ('tools_used', u''), ('special_training_required', None), ('what_training_required', u''), ('what_can_go_wrong', u''), ('effects_of_task', u''), ('special_vocabulary_used', u''), ('people_involved', u''), ('any_improvements', u''), ('how_important_improvement', u''), ('benefits_of_improvement', u''), ('stakeholder', 2L), ('project', 2L)]), 

OrderedDict([(u'id', 26), ('title', u'See latest arrivals of the books'), ('how_often', u'MO'), ('how_important_task', u'LI'), ('role', u'reader'), ('why_perform_task', u''), ('why_important_task', None), ('sequence_of_actions', u''), ('tools_used', u''), ('special_training_required', None), ('what_training_required', u''), ('what_can_go_wrong', u''), ('effects_of_task', u''), ('special_vocabulary_used', u''), ('people_involved', u''), ('any_improvements', u''), ('how_important_improvement', u''), ('benefits_of_improvement', u''), ('stakeholder', 2L), ('project', 1L)])]
```

As you can see there are total 4 Task objects returned. Each object has various keys/attributes like id, title etc and corresponding values.

I want to extract nouns and verbs only from values and not keys.

How can I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to create text from `values` and then operate with it:

```
text = ''.join([' '.join([str(y) for y in x.values()]) for x in serializer.data])
text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! There as a small syntax error: `text = ''.join([(str(x) for x in serializer.data.values())])` and it throws me `AttributeError: 'ReturnList' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: glad to help you